# R stackApply failed with large brick

Tags: r, large-data, r-raster

I have a very large brick of daily raster data for about 30 years.

I need to calculate the annual sum and I was trying to do it with stackApply.

```
sum <- stackApply(brick, yy, fun = sum)
```

I got the annual layers but all pixels are = 0

I have tried with a smaller data-set and I get the right results.

I have also run on a quite powerful PC but I have the some results.

Please can you help?

May be `stackApply` cannot manage a so large data-set, any other option/solution?

Thank you

Comment: can you be a bit more specific? how big are the raster? how many layers?

Comment: Hi, my stack is: dimensions  : 336, 221, 74256, 12784  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers). I am now trying with zApply and looks working properly. thanks

Comment: Perhaps the values of  `yy` are wrong?

Comment: I confirm that zApply works properly. yy values are ok as stackApply works properly with smaller rasters. thanks